# Can't get Koa-Router Route to Match

Tags: node.js, routes, koa

I cannot get this to match:

```
/people/locationId:12345
```

Notice yes, the colon is on the right side as opposed to the left side as you see in koa-router docs.  If it's on the left side that's a named param that lets anything come in.   The reason I tried having it on the right side is because I like the convention of allowing my callers to specify filter criteria in the uri itself.  That's a convention I've seen being used out there in various APIs.

Here was my attempt, my route definition, not sure what else to try, none of these attempts at creating the route work for me:

```
/people/([a-z-]+)locationId:?
/people/locationId([a-z-]+):?
/people/locationId:?
/people/:locationId:?
```

It does match this but only because the way this route is, it's a catch all that is able to take really any value.

'/people/:locationId?': { to: 'person#find' }

I can't use that especially when I have other routes defined such as:

'/people/:id': { to: 'person#findById' }

because it would hit this route, which is not the right route.

Comment: but why use a colon to separate the filter criteria? 
How about `/people/locationId/12345` that would be really easy to match.

Answer (score 0):

`/people/locationId::id`
matches
`/people/locationId:12345`

this.params.id then is '12345'

if locationId should also be variable,

`/people/:name::id`
matches
`/people/locationId:12345`

here this.params.id is '12345' and this.params.name is 'locationId'